# org.apache.commons.collections.BeanMap: can't find referenced class java.beans.Introspector

Tags: android, intellij-idea, proguard

I am trying to use Proguard for obfuscating my Android app. Also I am using IntelliJ Idea 11.1.3 to build the release signed APK with *Run Proguard* option selected in Open Module Settings -> Facets -> Compiler -> Run Proguard.

The application is compiling without any error when I don't use Proguard but with Proguard I am getting the below errors

```
Error:[MyApp] Warning: org.apache.commons.collections.BeanMap: can't find referenced class java.beans.Introspector
Error:[MyApp] Warning: org.apache.commons.collections.BeanMap: can't find referenced class java.beans.BeanInfo
Error:[MyApp] Warning: org.apache.commons.collections.BeanMap: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
Error:[MyApp] Warning: org.apache.commons.collections.BeanMap: can't find referenced class java.beans.IntrospectionException
Error:[MyApp] Warning: there were 14 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Error:[MyApp]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
Error:[MyApp] Error: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

How to remove these errors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have added the following lines and it removed the error

```
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.collections.BeanMap
-dontwarn java.beans.**
```

Comment: Okay you removed the error. But you don't seem to understand why the error was there. Or at least did not post it. Clearly states one is NOT to use dontwarn unless you know what is the reason. So I cannot accept your answer..

Comment: @StarWind You post detailed answer. I will accept you answer instead.

Comment: _"Only use -dontwarn option if you know what you're doing!"_, @GauravAgarwal, do you know what you are doing?